# Set random position to ImageView at start

Tags: java, android, layout, imageview

I have 8 ImageViews on my RelativeLayout.
When activity onCreate it starts method init:

```
 private void init() {
        gameFieldView = (RelativeLayout) getGameFieldView();
        mainView = (LinearLayout) getMainView();
        topOffset = mainView.getHeight() - gameFieldView.getHeight() - 6;
        // THERE ARE 0 height and width of gameFieldView, and mainView 
        for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS_NUMBER; i++) {
            ImageView letter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.e1_letter + i);
            generateRandomPosition(random, letter); // When i comment this line it is ok (What kind of sorcery is this?), but i want to set random position to ImageView "letter"
        }
    }
```

Now generateRandomPosition looks like

```
private void generateRandomPosition(Random random, ImageView letter) {
        int height = letter.getHeight();
        int width = letter.getWidth();
        int top = random.nextInt(gameFieldView.getMeasuredHeight() - height - topOffset); // It obviously crashes because of IllegalArgumentException - parameter < 0 because of gameFieldView height = 0 
        int left = random.nextInt(gameFieldView.getMeasuredWidth() - width);
        letter.layout(left, top, left + width, top + height);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**upd.**
By the way, i tried to call init() in onWindowFocusChanged, it solves the problem with IllegalArgumentException, top and left counts in the right way, but imageview stays in left top corner even after letter.layout()

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you would post your LogCat/StackTrace next time. Anyways, the problem is in the following line: `findViewById(R.id.e1_letter + i);` You're obtaining a reference id to a resource and adding an integer to it. That probably does not point to anything. Setting something on a null object won't work.
It would be much easier for you to loop through the children of the RelativeLayout, as follows:

```
ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) gameFieldView;
for(int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    ImageView letter = (ImageView) v.getChildAt(i);
    generateRandomPosition(random, letter); 
}
```

This way you will not need ids for all ImageViews

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but i'm pretty sure, what it's not a problem and id's in right order one by one. But, my exact question was about 0 in return of getHeight or getWidth of gameFieldView.